What is replace for OnAppearing method (Xamarin Forms) in Uno Platform?
I'm migrating an app from Xamarin Forms to Uno Platform. In my Xamarin app I'm overriding the OnAppearing method for handle the GoBack() method and reload the data in the original page.
i.e.
MainPage is loaded
**OnAppearing is called**
MainPage redirect to SecondPage
SecondPage is loaded
SecondPage GoBack to MainPage
**OnAppearing is called again**

I'm looking for the same behavior but in Uno Platform. I tried using the OnNavigatedFrom and OnNavigatedTo method but these are not called. I tried with NavigationCacheMode.Required but this not works either.
Do you know how can achieve my goal?
Thanks

Overriding OnNavigatedTo on your Page should be the way to go. Make sure you implement the navigation using a Frame and its methods such as Navigate and GoBack (and not just setting the Content of the Frame directly.
Alternatively, you might be able to achieve what you want by using the Loaded (and perhaps Unloaded) events. Those events are available on the FrameworkElement base class and are therefore not exclusive to Page.
